# Swift 2 - Simple Navigation With UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to write my first iOS app, but I'm having trouble with a simple problem. I want to figure out what's going on... can you please write me a simple code which can help me a lot?

Let's say I have 3 different UIViewControllers. One is the MainPage which contains 1 **UIButton**: "Food" If I click on this the FoodPage opens which has 2 buttons "Pie" and "Pizza" if I click on "Pizza" the PizzaPage opens if I click on "Pie" the PiePage opens. Both of PiePage and PizzaPage have 2 buttons one for FoodPage "Food" and one for MainPage "Main".

Can you please write me a code or give me some idea how to do something like this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go into main.storyboard.

Lay out the views.

Hold option, and left click and drag a button to the view you want to have it show. (If you have a mouse, you can right click and drag the button to the view)

The Action Segue options should show up. Hit "show". Now you're button will load that view controller.

Below I am dragging the cancel button to show the previous view controller.

Good luck. 
[Click here to see what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olGqR.png)

Comment: I did read your question. Apparently you want someone to make you YOUR first app. I just told you exactly how to have buttons open different view controllers, using a drag and drop. Did you still need someone to provide you with code? This isn't the place for that. You can do it man. Now read my answer.